# Vercel not rendering or not calling API

Tags: web, deployment, netlify, vercel, pancakeswap

Hello I am newbie in this thing and I don't understand where I am doing a mistake. I just forked pancakeswap to train myself on dapps and I deployed it on Vercel.

https://testpncake.vercel.app/prediction

This is what I deplyoed and the Game page. It works on localhost(yarn run start) fully operational. But when it comes deploy it not rendering or cannot pull something and it not shows up the Game.

It also not working when I run it with this method locally:

yarn run start -H (my.ip.add.ress) -p 3000

(It opens the website correctly but the Game still not loading as Vercel.)

https://pancakeswap.finance/prediction     This is original and works fine.

I didn't change any of codes, I m just trying to understand what cause this issue. Thanks.

Comment: did you figure this out? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: İt is due to: .env file try to remove the rpcs from there and trt again if you cannot make it work contact me: @asfhkmoglu